# Close SO question as a duplicate with link to documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, flags, documentation

There will always be general example questions on Stack Overflow where the OP is asking for example usage of some aspect of technology.

For example, LINQ JOIN:

- *[Join on Condition With Linq Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322485/join-on-condition-with-linq-methods)*
- *[inner join in linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176192/inner-join-in-linq-to-entities)*
- *[LINQ Left Join And Right Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497086/linq-left-join-and-right-join)*

etc.

Now we have [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) so this examples already exists in documentation:

*[Left, Right and Cross Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/2994/left-right-and-cross-outer-join#t=201607281349148214652)*

*[Joining on multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/8463/joining-on-multiple-keys#t=201607281349148214652)*

As long as [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) is highly integrated in Stack Overflow portal now, shouldn't these kind of questions (*newly added*) be closed with reason "**Documentation duplicate**"?

Will this option (reason) be added to ***flag*** and ***close*** modals?

Shouldn't it be available in review queues?